# Can apps be installed to or otherwise use the external SD card of the Galaxy Tab 2 7.0?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I have a Samsung Galaxy 2 7" wifi only tablet using ICS 4.0.3. Samsung states that all apps on ICS must run from internal storage (8Gb). I have a program that requires more storage for the data files than can fit in internal storage. I have a 32 Gb external microSD card installed with sufficient room for the data files. Is there a way for the app to be associated with the data files on my external storage card so that I can run the app?

Comment: Did Samsung specifically say this has to do with ICS? It sounds like the way they've configured their devices for a while now (with an "internal" SD card partition that apps would use).

Comment: Samsung said that this is a function of ICS.  The following is one of the answers given by Samsung on their Support site for the Galaxy Tab 2, 7".  "Thank you for contacting Samsung.

The SD card can be used to store media like videos, music and photos. Apps are programmed to work strictly with the Android OS."

Answer (score -1):

Use Samsung Kies to successfully connect your tab to PC, Samsung Kies supplies the drivers for your tab to be recognised by PC, when connecting you will also have the usual window pop up to give you access through explorer to both the card and the main tabs "drive", you can select through Kies where you place your media, internal or external. Hope this help.

Comment: Will Samsung Kies allow me to store and operate the application from the external storage card where I need to store the data files?

Comment: Yes, samsung kies is like iTunes in Apple products. It lets u download add and do all the things u need to do with the SD Card or your mobile in general

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the OP's question at all. The question is whether or not an installed app can use the external storage card - Kies has no bearing on this.